# Define and use MOCK_METHOD with gtest and gmock

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

I am new to googletest/googlemock and I have following questions:

**First question**: I have this DatabaseClient class which has a method query_items which I want to mock. I`m unable to find the syntax to do it. Here is my attempt:

```
class DatabaseClient {
  public:
    // constructors
    DatabaseClient();
    DatabaseClient(std::string base_url, std::string master_key);

    // destructor
    ~DatabaseClient();

    // properties
    some properties

    // methods
    // last parameter is optional with default value NULL
    CURLcode query_items(std::string databaseId, std::string containerId, std::string query, size_t (*p_callback_function)(void*, size_t, size_t, std::string*) = NULL);
};

class MockDatabaseClient {
    public:
        MOCK_METHOD(CURLcode, query_items, (std::string databaseId, std::string containerId, std::string query, size_t (*p_callback_function)(void*, size_t, size_t, std::string*));
        };
```

The MOCK_METHOD has compile errors, can you help in how to write it correctly?

**SECOND Question:** The Database client is used in a test service class which I want to test: Here is the sample of the method which I want to test:

```
#include "db/DatabaseClient.hpp"
#include "db/LibcurlCallbacks.hpp"

TestService::create() {
    DatabaseClient* databaseClient = new DatabaseClient();
    std::string body = "some query"
    try {
       auto respone = databaseClient->query_items(this->databaseName, this->containerName, body, \
            LibcurlCallbacks::CallbackFunctionOnCreate);

        return SomeObject;
    }
```

How can I mock the databaseClient->query_items in my test because I do not want to hit the database when running tests.

Here is the basic test I started:

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include "gmock/gmock.h" 

#include "../src/service/TestService.hpp"
#include "../src/db/DatabaseClient.hpp"
#include "../src/db/LibcurlCallbacks.hpp"


using ::testing::AtLeast;
TEST(HelloTest, BasicAssertions) {
  // Expect two strings not to be equal.
    MockCosmosClient cosmosClient;

    //EXPECT_CALL(cosmosClient, query_items("test", "test", "test", LibcurlCallbacks::CallbackFunctionOnDestinationCreate))

    TestService ds;
    auto response = ds.create();
  EXPECT_STRNE(response, "some string");

}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: **The MOCK_METHOD has compile errors** What errors do you get? Have you counted the opening and closing parenthesis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somehow you need to tell your `TestService` class to use the mock object instead of the real object.

Currently you instantiate the `DatabaseClient` in `create()`:

```cpp
TestService::create() {
    DatabaseClient* databaseClient = new DatabaseClient();
    //...
    }
```

You should tell it to use `MockDatabaseClient` instead. This can be done in several ways:

#### Use dependency injection:

Create an abstract class interface called `DatabaseClientInterface` that has virtual functions, then have your `MockDatabaseClient` and `DatabaseClient` inherit and implement that class.

Then rather than instantiating `databaseClient` in `TestService::create`, have a member variable in `TestService` of type `DatabaseClientInterface*` which can be initialized in the constructor of `TestService` by an object of either `MockDatabaseClient` for testing or `DatabaseClient` for production.

In your test you should then call:

```cpp
TEST(HelloTest, BasicAssertions) {
  MockDatabaseClient mock_client;
  TestService ds(&mock_client);
  //...
```

#### Templatize your class:

Make `TestService` a template class which creates the `databaseClient` object based on the template variable. Something like this:

```cpp
template <typename T>
class TestService
{
 //...
 create() {
    T* databaseClient = new DatabaseClient();
    //...
    }

};
```

Now for testing instantiate `TestService` with `MockDatabaseClient`.

See GMock documentations or [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vxCH4AuVRgo&t=835s) for an example of the first method and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vxCH4AuVRgo&t=4036s) for an example of the second method.

**Compile issues**

As for the compile issues with `MOCK_METHOD`, note that macros are limited and the preprocessor gets confused by seeing `,` in a macro parameter. I think you are hitting [this problem](https://youtu.be/vxCH4AuVRgo?t=1063).